# Line:54 What is the purpose two awk statements provided after grep chainID

Tags: linux, shell, docker, quorum

NETWORK_ID=$$(cat $${GENESIS_FILE} | grep chainId | awk -F " " '{print $$2}' | awk -F "," '{print $$1}')

https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-examples/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: Note that the `$$` are used instead of the normal `$` because this line is taken from a YAML file.

Answer (score 2):

awk 1: split string by space character, print column 2.

awk 2: split result of awk 1 by comma, print column 1.

So, if a line looks like:

```
foo bar,baz,qux something chainId
```

You will get `bar`.

Comment: You can also combine the two awks, plus the grep and the cat like `awk -F'[ ,]+' '/chainId/ { print $2 }' file`

Answer (score 0):

The first awk returns the value of the chainId, but it could have a trailing comma, e.g. "10,".
The second awk is just there to strip off the trailing comma.